# center site content on all devices

Tags: css, center

This is the site I am referring to: http://heattreatforum.flyten.net/

It was built as a child-site to the twenty-twelve theme.

I can't seem to get the content to center on every screen, and I am seeing a strange wide margin on the right that I just can't seem to locate in my css.

Any help would be much appreciated - thanks for looking!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your div having id `my-name` has `min-width: 1510px;`. Delete it and all your problems will disappear.

Comment: Thanks so much - at a certain point it seems that I completely lose perspective and miss dumb little things like that. Thank you for seeing it!